# tvOS 13 AVPlayerViewController live playback timestamp issue

Tags: tvos13

After updating to tvOS 13, I am seeing `18y8m0w4d` on the live progress bar when I rewind. This is fixed in a second or so when the progress bar gets updated. I don't see this issue on tvOS 12.
It looks like `AVPlayerViewController` bug but was wondering if anyone else is facing this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same issue on tvOS 13.0 and it looks like the latest update tvOS 13.2 has fixed it.